# Draw line between two markers in JQuery Mobile Map

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm using the Google Map plugin within a JQuery Mobile app. This app is currently adding markers at specific latitude/longitudinal points. I need to draw a line between the points. Is there a way to do this with the Google Map plugin? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the line to follow roads or just be straight line (great circle)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need a line between markerA and markerB, the following should work:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Polyline', { 
    'strokeColor': "#FF0000", 
    'strokeWeight': 2, 
    'path': [markerA.getPosition(), markerB.getPosition()]
  });
```

And if you already have the LatLng of the markers in some variables, of course you can just put those in the path array directly.